# PPTPd Client has No Network Acess

Tags: vpn, centos

So, I managed to install PPTPd onto my CentOS 6 server.

Windows 7 can connect to it, and login, but it has no network access.

Before I start pulling my recently cut hair out, please could someone help me??

**EDIT**

Error Log:

```
Oct  7 20:20:37 server pptpd[3900]: CTRL: Client 82.132.242.55 control connection started
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pptpd[3900]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pppd[3901]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pppd[3901]: pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pppd[3901]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pppd[3901]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  7 20:20:38 server pppd[3901]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
Oct  7 20:20:41 server pptpd[3900]: CTRL: Ignored a SET LINK INFO packet with real ACCMs!
Oct  7 20:20:42 server pppd[3901]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Oct  7 20:20:44 server pppd[3901]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
Oct  7 20:20:44 server pppd[3901]: local  IP address 192.168.0.1
Oct  7 20:20:44 server pppd[3901]: remote IP address 192.168.2.2
Oct  7 20:20:44 server pppd[3901]: pptpd-logwtmp.so ip-up ppp0 liamw 82.132.242.55
Oct  7 20:20:53 server pppd[3901]: LCP terminated by peer (uM-jn$^@<M-Mt^@^@^@^@)
Oct  7 20:20:53 server pppd[3901]: pptpd-logwtmp.so ip-down ppp0
Oct  7 20:20:53 server pppd[3901]: Connect time 0.2 minutes.
Oct  7 20:20:53 server pppd[3901]: Sent 0 bytes, received 16518 bytes.
Oct  7 20:20:54 server pppd[3901]: Modem hangup
Oct  7 20:20:54 server pppd[3901]: Connection terminated.
Oct  7 20:20:54 server pppd[3901]: Exit.
Oct  7 20:20:54 server pptpd[3900]: CTRL: Client 82.132.242.55 control connection finished
```

I have to disconnect, or I cannot use my internet.

My default gateway is also listed as 0.0.0.0 - could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by opening up the `/etc/pptpd.conf` file.

In this file I found the `LocalIP` entry, and changed it to the static external IP of my VPS.

Once that had been done, I saved and closed the file, and then restarted PoPToP (`service pptpd restart`).

I then proceeded to connect to the VPN using the default Windows system, and this time the connection worked correctly.

Comment: Can you expand your answer so that we can understand precisely what you did, such as where you made these changes?  As it stands, your answer doesn't contain enough detail for it to be useful.